# How do you make a CollectionEditor modeless?

Tags: .net, propertygrid, collectioneditor

Using a PropertyGrid, how can I make the collection editor that opens when I click a list parameter become modeless instead of modal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new type of CollectionEditor:

```
public class SmartCollectionEditor : CollectionEditor
{
```

Override the 'EditValue' form to open the collection form modelessly instead of modal, and remove the accept and cancel buttons because changes will take effect immediately.

```
public override object EditValue(ITypeDescriptorContext context, IServiceProvider provider, object value)
{
        CollectionForm collectionForm = base.CreateCollectionForm();
    collectionForm.EditValue = value;
    (collectionForm.AcceptButton as Button).Visible = false;
    (collectionForm.CancelButton as Button).Visible = false;
    collectionForm.Show();
    return value;
}
```

Mark the types that you want to use this with an attribute that will make the PropertyGrid open it.

```
TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(typeof(List<MyType>), new EditorAttribute(typeof(SmartCollectionEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor)));
```